# How to use 'LIKE' in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

**I'm trying to use 'LIKE' in Laravel. But in the output whole data is displayed. Is my method correct? If not then correct me.**

```
        $this->uses('Data');
        $a ='nan';
        $options = ['sort' => ['city' => 1]];
        $results = $this->Part->find([],['city','LIKE',"%$a%"],$options);
        return view('testEnv')->with('results',$results);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query Builder

```
$data = DB::table('table_name')->where('col_name','LIKE','%'.$variable.'%')->get();
```

"%$a%" is a string ....

Comment: @Ajay Kakede , i think this can be found by googling, such questions , sadly , get lots of downvote here.

Comment: Call to undefined method MongoDB\Driver\Cursor::where()  I got this error..

Comment: Try Postgres or Mysql if you're new. 
https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb
Refer to mongodb docs

Comment: I tried by googling.. But it didn't worked for me..

Comment: '%'.$variable.'%'

Answer (score 0):

You can use where like

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                ->where('name', 'like', 'T%')
                ->get();
```

Read documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries)